# Run str_replace on title and save the output to a custom field

Tags: php, custom-field, title

I need to a make a custom RSS template for my website and I'm having problems getting `substr(the_title_rss(), 0, strpos(the_title_rss(), ' —'));` to work on the RSS feed.

What the above code is suppose to do is if a title has `-` in the title, it removes everything after the `-`.

I think the best way to solve my problem is to run `substr` and `strpos` and save the title in a custom field. I'm not a programmer so has anyone been able to accomplish this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title_rss()` outputs its value straight away so it can't be used in a function like that, you would have to use `get_the_title_rss()`

Or alternatively the_title_rss() has a filter we can hook in to and return your shortened title is possible. (You would add this to your functions.php)

```
function gg_short_title_rss($title)
{
    // This can return false, so check there is something
    $short_title = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#8211;'));
    if ($short_title) {
        return $short_title;
    }

    // Else just return the normal title
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'gg_short_title_rss', 10, 1);
```